# r plot time series abline strange behavior

Tags: r, datetime, plot, time-series

I have an unusual problem. I want to create a abline for R time series plot. When I do that it always shifts by 1 month.

See below for a reproducible example:

```
library(datasets)
tsdata = window(datasets::AirPassengers,start=c(1956,1),end=c(1960,12))
plot(tsdata,type="o")
abline(v=(1956+5/12),col="red")
```

As you can see from the chart below, the abline is drawn in the **June** of 1956, *not* in **May** of 1956 as requested by command in `abline` in `R` code: `v=(1956+5/12)`.

Not sure how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: hmm... when I run your code, I don't get a vertical line *at all*. You may want to revisit what's needed here for a [mcve]. For example, you should add `library(datasets)` to the beginning of your code, and we should be able to reproduce your problem from a **fresh** R session using *only* the code you provide. So you may need to add other code statements (perhaps including `library()` statements to ensure we have the same loaded packages)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I have updated my question, still getting the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to change then convert to `yearmon` from `zoo` and to `numeric`

```
library(zoo)
p1 <- as.numeric(zoo::as.yearmon("1956/05/01", "%Y/%m/%d"))
```

Or it can be derived from `time`.  As the frequency is 12, we can select the 5th element which would be for `May` of 1956

```
p1 <- time(tsdata)[5]
abline(v = p1, col="red")
```

-output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the comment, this is not a suitable minimum reproducible example as your code doesn't give me a red vertical line either.

Nevertheless, the solution is that plot.ts in this case has decimal years as the x-axis. Therefore, your v coordinate must be 1956 + (5/12), or 1956.417.

```
abline(v=1956.417,col="red")
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I'm getting the same plot.

Comment: sorry, I realized my answer doesn't actually fix your issue

Answer (score 1):

You have 12 points(months) fitted in 1 year which is actually a numeric value. After adding 5/12 you also need to normalize it with 10/12.

```
tsdata = window(datasets::AirPassengers,start=c(1956,1),end=c(1960,12))
plot(tsdata,type="o")
abline(v=(1956 + 5/12 * 10/12),col="red")
```

[image]